# Show last 3 characters in an input only on focus?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have inputs with hours and minutes in them, but I only want the minutes to show up if the input is focused. Is this possible?

My current approach uses jQuery to add the full time, but it would be ideal to have the full time as the value the whole time and just show what is necessary.

Also the cursor doesn't end up where you click in the input because of this (the cursor shows up at the end instead. At least in FF).

Other smarter ideas? It's not possible to do it just with css right? Set the color of the last 3 characters to transparent or similar when not focused.

```js
$('input').on('focus', function(e) {
  var full_time = $(this).attr('data-full-time');
  $(this).val(full_time);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" data-full-time="12:30" data-short-time="12" value="12" />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the cursor to be in the right place, you can use a fake form field. This is mostly CSS and only JS to sync up the fields. (From your example I assume you meant you want only **hours** to show up, not only **minutes**.)

```js
$('#real').on('input', function(e) {
  $('#fake').val($(this).val().split(':')[0]);
});
```

```css
.input-container {
  position: relative;
}

.input-container input {
  position: absolute;
}

#fake {
  pointer-events: none;
}

#real {
  opacity: 0;
}

#real:focus {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="input-container">
  <input id="fake" type="text" value="12" />
  <input id="real" type="text" value="12:30" />
 </div>
```

Comment: Man, that's pretty clever. I guess a div with contenteditable would have solved it too, but I prefer input in this case. Thanks

Comment: Didn't know about contenteditable, thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: Yeah I use it instead of textareas where I needed them to fit the text heightwise without JS. It’s a little messy but works.

Answer (score 0):

Simply have a .focus and blur option and use the one time ("12:30") but in the .blur() option - split it at the ":" and display just the first part.

Try focussing in and out of the field to see this in action.

```js
$('input').on('focus', function(e) {
  var time = $(this).attr('data-time');
  $(this).val(time);
});

$('input').on('blur', function(e) {
  var time = $(this).attr('data-time').split(":")[0];
  $(this).val(time);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" data-time="12:30"  autofocus/>
```

Comment: Yes, but how can I get the cursor to be where you click (in FF)? I assume there’s no way to have the whole text in the value and show and hide parts of it? E.g. not replace anything. The input will be editable so I’ll need a function to hide the last 3 characters on blur but if the focus work I can figure out the blur part.

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<input id="timeInput" value="12:30" onfocus="showMinutesOnly()" onblur="showWholeTime()"/>
```

And some JavaScript:

```
var wholeTimeString;
var minutes;

function showMinutesOnly(){
  wholeTimeString = document.getElementById("timeInput").value;
  minutes = wholeTimeString.substring(wholeTimeString.indexOf(":")+1);

  document.getElementById("timeInput").value = minutes;
}

function showWholeTime(){
  document.getElementById("timeInput").value = wholeTimeString;
}
```

Example: http://jsbin.com/rumaveguwe/1/edit?html,js,console,output